# How can I show multiple lines in a single plot in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- tribble(~Name, ~Numeric,
              "Python", 9, 
              "R", 14,
              "Java", 3, 
              "Python", 6, 
              "R", 20,)
```

And I want to create a plot where each of the 'Name' items are represented by 3 distinct lines on the same plot (one line for 'Python', one for 'R', and one for 'Java')

I've tried this code but I am getting errors:

```
df_viz <- ggplot(data= df, aes(x= Name,y=Numeric)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = filter(df, Name == "Python"))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = filter(df, Name == "R"))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = filter(df, Name == "Java")))
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I'm not sure about drawing line between `character` and `numeric`, but try `ggplot(df, aes(Name, Numeric, group = Name)) +
  geom_line()
`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use subset of your data for a `geom` layer you have to pass it to the `data` argument not to the aesthetics, e.g. you could e.g. do `geom_line(data = filter(df, Name == "Python"))`. However, there is no reason to so. You could achieve your desired result with just one `geom_line`.

Note: IMHO you data lacks a variable which you be mapped on the `x` axis or which give meaning to the different obs. per programming language.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Name, y = Numeric, color = Name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]